# What are weak external symbols and when are they generated?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

My C++ application uses `dlopen` and friends to implement a plugin system, where shared libraries are loaded as necessary.The plugins depend on classes that are currently defined in the executable itself.

I was surprised to find, that the plugins successfully compile without somehow "*linking the plugin to the executable*". In other words, the plugins compile without having a definition for the relevant classes. To investigate the situation, I looked at the symbols of the plugin's object file using `nm -m thePlugin.o`.

In the output of `nm`, the symbols that are defined in the executable are listed as `(__TEXT,__textcoal_nt) weak external`. The wikipedia article on [weak symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) states

> When linking a binary executable, a weakly declared symbol does not
>   need a definition

So this seems to be the explanation for why the compilation is successful.

**Question A:** In which cases are these weak external symbols generated? Is this a portable mechanism (at least for OS X and Linux)?

**Question B:** When my plugin references a statically allocated variable (static class member or global `extern` variable) that symbol is not `weak external` but `unknown` and compilation fails, probably due to the lack of a definition. Can I make these symbols weak external as well or alternatively, can I link my plugins with the binary somehow?

Comment: It is completely implementation dependent, but compilers may generate weak symbols for inline functions, template instantiations, and vtables. You need to provide a definition for a static data member if it is being used.

Comment: Weak symbols are generated if they are annotated `weak`. It is definitely not portable, because it breaks ODF. It is feature of the ELF binary format, and availble on Linux, Solaris, FreeBSD, and it might work with restrictions of OS X. You could mark symbol weak by doing `__attribute__((weak))`